# Isolator’s (ISO7720) recommended current

Tags: datasheet, digital-isolator

I have a design which uses an [ISO7720](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso7720.pdf) digital isolator, with a 3.3 V supply voltage.

My output load is 500 Ω. Due to area constraints, I’d like to avoid adding a buffer on the output, if I can.

The datasheet specifies an absolute max output current of +/- 15 mA, so I would be well within that rating. But the recommended current is +/- 2 mA.

[image: recommended current]

Maybe the recommended current is just to keep the output voltage within some tolerance of V<sub>CCO</sub>?

I don’t see any rationale in the datasheet as to why the recommended current is so low, other than Figure 11, which plots the device’s voltage loading vs output current:

[image: voltage loading]

If my design can tolerate the reduced voltage<sup>1</sup>, is it safe to proceed? Am I overlooking something?

My data rate is ~30 Mbps.

<sup>1</sup> From the curve, it looks like my output might be around 3.1 V

Comment: Higher output currents (aka heavier loads) probably have lower data rates. The output waveforms won't be as pristine.

Comment: Take a look at the output waveforms and see if there is any distortion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electrical and switching characteristics are guaranteed only as long as you stay inside the recommended operating conditions.

When you draw a higher output current, the voltage drop will be higher. Figure 11 shows only typical values; you do not know how large the actual voltage drop might be.

Power dissipation (< 2 mW, assuming a 0.3 V drop) appears to be safe, and the higher load should not affect the speed at which the output transister themselves are able to switch. So as long as your load works with the reduced voltage, it should be fine.

Comment: Ok, this sounds good. Just to clarify, your first sentence seems to contrast with "the higher load should not affect the speed at which the output transistor themselves are able to switch". Are you suggesting that my 30 Mbps is not guaranteed (since I'm outside of the +/- 2 mA), but should be fine?

Comment: TI will not guarantee anything. But I see no physical reason why the data rate (as opposed to the voltage range) should be reduced.